# How to return text from HTML without tag using python and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am stuck trying to return text from a website.  I am trying to return ownerId and unitId from the following example.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
    h1.config.days = "7";
    h1.config.hours = "24";
    h1.config.color = "blue";
    h1.config.ownerId = 7321;
    h1.config.locationId = 1258;
    h1.config.unitId = "164";
</script>
```

Comment: Since this part is not html, use regex to extract the data you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Beautiful Soup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<script>
    h1.config.days = "7";
    h1.config.hours = "24";
    h1.config.color = "blue";
    h1.config.ownerId = 7321;
    h1.config.locationId = 1258;
    h1.config.unitId = "164";
</script>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
jsinfo = soup.find("script")

d = {}
for line in jsinfo.text.split('\n'):
    try:
        d[line.split('=')[0].strip().replace('h1.config.','')] = line.split('=')[1].lstrip().rstrip(';')
    except IndexError:
        pass

print 'OwnerId:  {}'.format(d['ownerId'])
print 'UnitId:   {}'.format(d['unitId'])
```

This will produce the following result:

```
OwnerId:  7321
UnitId:   "164"
```

Also in this way you can access any other variable too, by doing `d['variable']`.

**Update**

Now in case you have to deal with multiple `<script>` tags, to iterate through them you can do:

```
jsinfo = soup.find_all("script")
```

Now, `jsinfo` is type of `<class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>` which you can iterate through like a normal *list*.

Now to extract *lat* and *lon* you could simply do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.your_url'
# the user-agent you specified in the comments
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17'}

html = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
jsinfo = soup.find_all("script")

list_of_interest = ['hl.config.lat', 'hl.config.lon']

d = {}
for line in jsinfo[9].text.split('\n'):
    if any(word in line for word in list_of_interest):
        k,v = line.strip().replace('hl.config.','').split(' = ')
        d[k] = v.strip(';')

print 'Lat => {}'.format(d['lat'])
print 'Lon => {}'.format(d['lon'])
```

This will produce the following results:

```
Lat => "28.06794"
Lon => "-81.754349"
```

By appending more values in `list_of_interest` you can access some other variables too if you like!

Comment: Thank you for your response.  How does this work if there is more than one <script> </script>?

Comment: Also, I was using urllib.request.Request using headers['User-Agent'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"

Comment: @JustinHill, Yes, the script that you are actually referring to is totally different than the one you posted, thus the KeyError. I updated the answer accordingly. Also the results are from the url you posted in the comments, I just replaced it in the answer for typical reasons.

Comment: Because of my reputation being less than 15 on here, I am unable to give you a +1 that counts.  However, I truly appreciate all of your help.